# Duplicate values when using HashMap in java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a problem when using a Map

What I need to do is to build this matrix using hashmap

```
   A B C D  
 A o di o o   
 B o di o o  
 C o di o di  
 D di o o di
```

o and di represent the relation (value) between Activities {A,B,C,D}
Also with each relation I need to attach its timestamp 
So, I created a map like this

```
Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Object>>> map = new HashMap<String,Map<String, ArrayList<Object>>>();
```

As this map worked as follows

```
A --> B --> {o,specific timestamp}
```

So, I need the result to be

For A,
Relation between A and B is di and with specific timestamp t1
Also, the relation between it and C is o and with specific timestamp t2

I need this for each activity.

But the output from the code appeared

```
A {B = [o,specific timestamp,di,specfic timestamp] , C = [o,specific timestamp,di,specfic timestamp]}
```

but I need the output to be

```
A {B = [di,specfic timestamp] , C = [o,specific timestamp]}
```

What can I do?

```
ArrayList<Object> fill_data = new ArrayList<Object>();
public void activityRelationShip(ArrayList<Eventlog> data, ArrayList<String> activities) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IOException {
    Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Object>>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Object>>>();


    for (int i = 0; i < activities.size(); i++) {
        map.put(activities.get(i), new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>());
    }
    ArrayList<Object> s = new ArrayList<Object>();
    int index = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    // here we will add corrsponding activities and relation between them and also timestamp
    for (int j = 0; j < activities.size(); j++) {
        index = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < data.size(); y++) {
            if (data.get(y).getActivity().equalsIgnoreCase(activities.get(j)) == true && data.get(y).getAbstractState().equalsIgnoreCase("Active") == true) {
                index = y;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int k = index; k < data.size(); k++) {
            if (data.get(k).getActivity().equalsIgnoreCase(activities.get(j)) == false) {
                if (data.get(k).getAbstractState().equalsIgnoreCase("Active") == true) {
                    for (int i = k + 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(data.get(i).getActivity() + " -- > " + data.get(k).getActivity());
                        if (data.get(i).getActivity().equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(k).getActivity()) == true
                                && data.get(i).getAbstractState().equalsIgnoreCase("Idle") == true) {
                            map.get(activities.get(j)).put(data.get(k).getActivity(), fill_data);
                            flag = true;
                            break;
                        } else if (data.get(i).getActivity().equalsIgnoreCase(activities.get(j)) == true && data.get(i).getAbstractState().equalsIgnoreCase("Idle") == true) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag == true) {
                        flag =false;
                        map.get(activities.get(j)).get(data.get(k).getActivity()).add("di");
                        map.get(activities.get(j)).get(data.get(k).getActivity()).add(data.get(k).getTime());
                    } else {
                        map.get(activities.get(j)).put(data.get(k).getActivity(), fill_data);
                        map.get(activities.get(j)).get(data.get(k).getActivity()).add("o");
                        map.get(activities.get(j)).put(data.get(k).getActivity(), fill_data);
                        map.get(activities.get(j)).get(data.get(k).getActivity()).add(data.get(k).getTime());
                    }
                } // close if "Active"
            } else if (data.get(k).getActivity().equalsIgnoreCase(activities.get(j)) == true && data.get(k).getAbstractState().equalsIgnoreCase("Idle")) {
                break;
            }

            s = map.get(activities.get(j)).get(data.get(k).getActivity());
        }
        if (s != null) {
            System.out.println("Entry set " + map.get(activities.get(j)).entrySet());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you stepping through your code in a debugger (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans) and examining variables?  That is the simplest way to find out what is actually happening.

Comment: I'd love to help you but the code you added is simply saying impossible to read. Maybe try writing some unit test and then refactoring it?

Comment: I solved the problem thanks :)